# Get guild members and filter them (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i'm new to Discord.js, and trying to make server info command like on the picture below. I'm stuck in the moment where i need to get all guild members and filter them by current status and `bot` property. I read https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html and it says that i need to fetch all guild members:

```js
msg.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
    const totalOnline = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online');
    msg.channel.send(`There are currently ${totalOnline.size} members online in this guild!`);
});
```

My command is sent as an embed, and i'm adding filtered members count into a variable, and then this value inserting into a embed field. If i send embed to a channel right inside then() block, it's working, embed fields are added correctly. But i need to add another information about guild, such as channels count, owner, region etc. If i create fields out of then(), instead of the count i get `undefined`.

P.S. sorry for my poor English, i'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` is because `fetch()` is an asynchronous function, meaning it is completed in the background, and once it is completed, the callback `then` is called.

You can't put it outside the `then()` block because then your code will execute before `fetch()` finished and updated the variable with a result, in addition to that, the `totalOnline` variable is created inside that block, so it wouldn't work outside of it either way, since it's a local variable inside that scope.

This article might make it easier to understand: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/async-await-javascript-tutorial/

You can use the additional needed information inside that scope.
For example:

```
msg.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
    const totalOnline = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online');
    msg.channel.send(`There are currently ${totalOnline.size} members online in ${msg.guild.name}!`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to read this article, I think it should help.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead of using `fetch()` is just assign a variable to the member collection.

```
// v12
let allmembers = message.guild.members.cache;

// v11
let allmembers = message.guild.members;
```

Once you have that, you can filter it and put it into an embed or message etc.

```
const totalOnline = allmembers.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online');

message.channel.send(`There are currently ${totalOnline.size} members online in ${message.guild.name}!`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for `discord.js v13`:

```
let members = (await guild.members.fetch())
    .filter(m => m._roles.includes(ROLE_ID));

let member_ids = members.map(m => m.user.id);

let member_count = members.size();
```