# Discord.js: What method should I use to ban everyone whose username contains 'x'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

My server has experienced massive raids and so I wish to make a command that can ban all members whose usernames contain a certain word.

**The main problem is: I don't understand what method to use to ban everyone whose username contains argument.**
I don't ask for you to create a command for me.

**Code**

```js
let target_word = args[0];

    message.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
        const target_users = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.user.username.includes(target_word))
        target_users.ban({reason:reason})
        })`
```

Return an error:

> (node:673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: target_users.ban is not a function

**For example**

`!ban_all raid` to ban all members whose names contain the word `raid`

Comment: Can you show us any code? :) Because we're not going to write code for you, StackOverflow's purpose is to help you find and / or fix **bugs** in **your code** ^^

Comment: Hey @Toasty, thank you for commenting, unfortunately, I don't have a FULL code, because I don't understand what method to use to ban everyone whose username contains argument, I edited a post.

Comment: Your code doesn't have to be complete, just show us what you've got so far :)

Comment: Simply [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=fetch) all your guild members, check [each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) member and [ban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) it if necessary. ;)

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to read the official **discord.js guide** and to use the **documentation** while coding, since it's structured really good

Comment: @Toasty thank you for suggestions and for trying to help, I did read discord.js documentation, but did not understand how to filter users.

Comment: Your code looks alright, but you won't be able to use the `target_users` because it is **scoped** inside the `then` block. You can either declare `target_users` **before** the `then` block and "fill" it afterwards, **or** you can simply use `await`, which would be easier and better looking :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to discord.js documentation, you can use the function "ban" on a guildmember object:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban

I found this question on SO to show you how to get and filter your guild members:
[Get guild members and filter them (Discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349914/get-guild-members-and-filter-them-discord-js)

Get members, filter on username, ban them

EDIT:
Your provided code looks good, now you have to loop through your target users and ban them:

```
let target_word = args[0];
message.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
    const target_users = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.user.username.includes(target_word));
    target_users.forEach(user => user.ban());
}
```

A side note: Make sure your bot only acts on messages from your Mods otherwise everyone could ban anyone

Comment: Hey, thank you for the question, it really did help, but can I ask you if my code is alright:
`let target_word = args[0];

        
    message.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
    const target_users = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.user.username.includes(target_word));`

Comment: @eightless I think it would make sense, if you add this code to your question instead of adding it as a comment because not everybody will recognize this if they look at this question the first time :D

Comment: Phil, I have updated the code in my question, it gives an error: (node:673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: target_users.ban is not a function

Comment: Hi @eightless, please see my response above, you have to loop through your target users.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has solved my problem!